# Collision is skipping certain quads

Tags: c#, opengl, game-physics, opentk

I've formulated my own collision system in a modified version of OpenTK. It works by running a `foreach` loop which checks all the quads in the game (this runs when something moves) and sets their position back to where it was last frame, that is if it intersects this frame. I might not have explained that well, so here is the `SetXVelocity` code, called when a player moves right.

```
public void SetXVelocity(float x)
        {
            foreach (Quad quad in quads)
            {
                if (!quad.Equals(this))
                {
                    if (Intersects(quad))
                    {
                        Velocity.x = 0;
                        Position = OldPosition;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!Intersects(quad))
                    {
                        OldPosition = Position;
                        Velocity.x = x;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    OldPosition = Position;
                    continue;
                }
                OldPosition = Position;
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for `Intersects`:

```
public bool Intersects(Quad quad)
        {
            #region
            if (TLCorner.x > quad.TLCorner.x && TLCorner.x < quad.BRCorner.x && TLCorner.y < quad.TLCorner.y && TLCorner.y > quad.BRCorner.y)
            {
                 return true;
            }
            if (BRCorner.x < quad.BRCorner.x && BRCorner.x > quad.TLCorner.x && BRCorner.y > quad.BRCorner.y && BRCorner.y < quad.TLCorner.y)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (TRCorner.x < quad.TRCorner.x && TRCorner.x > quad.BLCorner.x && TRCorner.y < quad.TRCorner.y && TRCorner.y > quad.BLCorner.y)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (BLCorner.x > quad.BLCorner.x && BLCorner.x < quad.TRCorner.x && BLCorner.y > quad.BLCorner.y && BLCorner.y < quad.TRCorner.y)
            {
                return true;
            }
            #endregion // Corner Intersection
            if (Math.Round(Left, 2) == Math.Round(quad.Right, 2) && TRCorner.y > quad.TRCorner.y && BRCorner.y < quad.BRCorner.y)
                return true;
            if (Math.Round(Right, 2) == Math.Round(quad.Left, 2) && TRCorner.y > quad.TRCorner.y && BRCorner.y < quad.BRCorner.y)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

By the way, TRCorner is a Vector3 representing the Top Right Corner etc.

Last block of code is the `Quad` class, keep in mind, the actual class is huge, so I'll try not include all of it:

```
public Vector3 Velocity;
public Vector3 Position;
public int Index;
public VBO<Vector3> VertexData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public VBO<int> VertexCount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public VBO<Vector2> VertexTexture
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

For some reason, a few quads have no collision and some do. Some even have collision that makes the player stick to them.

Comment: I didn't have the patience to look at all the code, but at best your intersection code looks overly complicated. It takes 4 comparisons to check if two rectangles overlap, and I counted 22 comparisons.in your code. If you have problems deriving the logic yourself, it shouldn't be hard to find code online. It's fairly easy though if you start thinking about it. Hint: At least for me, it's easier to write down the 4 conditions where the rectangles do **not** overlap, and then negating the logical expression.

Comment: Hmm... You've, made me realize that now. I'll have a go at this later, but I really want to know why this isn't working, even if it's overly complicated. The reality is that I am designing a game engine with OpenGL and the code here is simplified **a lot** from what it is in VS. Thanks for the comment though @RetoKoradi.

Comment: Try something easier like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection Player sticks to them cause you use `>` and `<` so by the time you check collision, the rectangles are inside one another and collide for ever.

Comment: Thanks @Harish, I still don't understand why it is skipping certain quads.

Comment: One thing - if `A` and `B` intersect, you move the first one that's checked, which will affect the result when you check the second quad.Is that what you intended? Also, do you have some beef with `else`?

Comment: Yes @DavidLivel, `else` has offended me deeply. Nah, I suppose I just forget to add it.

Comment: @DenverP. :) Just curious! Also, don't forget to check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: One more thing -If your first case `if(Intersects(..))` changes things so they don't intersect, won't your second case `if(!Intersects())` ALSO execute? Really, change it to an `else`. This is a pretty classic mistake. Also, calling `Intersects()` twice when it's not necessary is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think some quads are missing because all possible conditions are not covered in your comparisons.

Since you `&&` all your conditions, a collision needs to meet all your conditions to get detected.

```
if (TLCorner.x > quad.TLCorner.x && TLCorner.x < quad.BRCorner.x && TLCorner.y < quad.TLCorner.y && TLCorner.y > quad.BRCorner.y)
        {
             return true;
        }
```

`if( TLCorner.x == quad.TLCorner.x && TLCorner.y < quad.TLCorner.y && TLCorner.y > quad.BRCorner.y )` the rectangle still collides, but undetected.

Same for other conditions.

You might want to use `>=` and `<=` in your code in order to cover all conditions.

As for why they get stuck in one another, your velocity probably pushes them into a condition which makes them collide forever, since you detect the collision after they went into each other and not when the boundaries overlap.

Also you might want to reverse the velocity and "un-stuck" them when collision is detected in a way that does not make them stuck in other nearby rectangles.

> I highly recommend you use better logic for collision detection

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/knam8/

Comment: I switched to that method in the link, with >=, and it's still happening.

Comment: I was suggesting `>=` and `<=` for your code, don't use it for the code in the link, I think that code works as is. You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/knam8/

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot when I'm back on my pc

Comment: Tried this, some quads are still 'sticking', and some are skipped altogether. This error is really annoying me...

Comment: Maybe your velocity is too high compared to your quad size,  and so they get stuck or jump over each other.

Comment: Maybe, I'll lower it.